# OpenCV calibrateCamera how to match corner points after undistort to objectPoints provided

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to undistort the following 2500X2000 picture 
[image]
to its original state
[image]
I'm using the following code

```
//ptCircleCenter is a array of 25 circle center points detected in the distorted image


//prepare object_points and image_points
vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;
vector<Point3f> object_point;
vector<Point2f> image_point;
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; ++j) {
        //object_point corresponds to circle center coordinates in the original picture before distortion
        object_point.push_back(Point3f(250 + i * 500, 200 + j * 400, 0));   
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i <= 24; ++i) {
    image_point.push_back(Point2f(ptCircleCenter[i].x, ptCircleCenter[i].y));
}
object_points.push_back(object_point);
image_points.push_back(image_point);


//prepare distCoeffs rvecs tvecs
Mat distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(5, 1, CV_64F);
vector<Mat> rvecs;
vector<Mat> tvecs;


//calculate principal point
Point2f tFImageCenter;
tFImageCenter.x = 0.;
tFImageCenter.y = 0.;
for (int i=0;i<5*5;i++)
{
    tFImageCenter.x = tFImageCenter.x+ ptCircleCenter[i].x;
    tFImageCenter.y = tFImageCenter.y+ ptCircleCenter[i].y;
}
tFImageCenter.x = tFImageCenter.x / 25;
tFImageCenter.y = tFImageCenter.y / 25;
//prepare camera matrix
Mat intrinsic = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
intrinsic.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1.0f;
intrinsic.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1.0f;
intrinsic.ptr<float>(0)[2] = tFImageCenter.x;
intrinsic.ptr<float>(1)[2] = tFImageCenter.y;

//solve calibration
calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, Size(2500,2000), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);


//apply undistortion
Mat imageUndistorted;
undistort(imgray, imageUndistorted, intrinsic, distCoeffs);
string outputName = "../corrected grid.jpg";
imwrite(outputName, imageUndistorted); // A JPG FILE IS BEING SAVED
```

**Result**

And the ouput image is 
[image]
,which enlarges the grid and loses the information around the grid.

I tried modifying the imageSize parameter

```
calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, Size(4000,3200), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
```

And the output image becomes
[image]

**Question1**

So is there a way to exactly match the coordinates of the corner points after undistort to the objectPoints provided to calibrateCamera, like *getPerspectiveTransform*, which maintains the size 
 of the grid?

**Question2**

Also I'm encountering exception that does not terminate the program:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCF8A07788 in Demo.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000E870EFB810.
```

And when I tryied to add flag *cv::CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS* to calibrateCamera:

```
calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, Size(2500,2000), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, cv::CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS);
```

Two exceptions are thrown and the second one terminates the program at this line

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCF8A07788 in Demo.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000E870EFB810.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCF8A07788 in Demo.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000E870EFB810.
```

I'm using VS2015 and OpenCv 3.1.0 with x64 debug mode.

Could someone help me with these two questions? Thanks.

**Added**
OK. I solved second exception. I changed the definition of *intrinsic* to this,  and no exception was thrown when cv::CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS was set.

```
Mat intrinsic = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
```

I don't know why. And the first exception is still there.

Actually this is the first half of my calibration process. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679422/opencv-get-topdown-view-of-planar-pattern-by-using-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-from)
contains the full process. And the scale modification in *undistort* still concersn me, as I need to preserve the information of the distorted picture after *undistort* for further use in *warpPerspective*.

**Added 2**
The scale problem is solved with *getOptimalNewCameraMatrix*. The detailed explanation is posted to the above So question link.

Answer (score 0):

Transformation you are performing is fully valid. In case of single image algorithm provide transformation, of what results you provided.

If you want to have better results, try to change object points definition, since when intrinsic matrix is set to `I` object coordinates are your "ideal" image coordinates.

If you have any doubts or questions, please comment - i will expand my answer.

Comment: The produced intrinsic matrix is {95642.7  0 1307.13 ,0  87092.2  999.268,  0 0 1}. Should I set intrinsic matrix to identity before pass it to calibrateCamera and set flag to cv::CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS? But how should I deal with the exception? Thanks.