# OpenCV get topdown view of planar pattern by using intrinsic and extrinsic from cameraCalibrate

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

Originally I have a image with a perfect circle grid, denoted as ***A***
[image]
I add some lens distortion and perspective transformation to it, and it becomes  ***B***
[image]
In camera calibration, ***A*** would be my destination image, and ***B*** would be my source image.
Let's say I have all the circle center coordinates in both images, stored in *stdPts* and *disPts*.

```
//25 center pts in A
vector<Point2f> stdPts;
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; ++j) {
        stdPts[i * 5 + j].x = 250 + i * 500;
        stdPts[i * 5 + j].y = 200 + j * 400;
    }
}
//25 center pts in B
vector<Point2f> disPts = FindCircleCenter();
```

I want to generate an image ***C*** that is as close as ***A***, from input: ***B***, *stdPts* and *disPts*.
I tried to use the intrinsic and extrinsic generated by cv::calibrateCamera. Here is my code:

```
//prepare object_points and image_points
vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;
object_points.push_back(stdPts);
image_points.push_back(disPts);


//prepare distCoeffs rvecs tvecs
Mat distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(5, 1, CV_64F);
vector<Mat> rvecs;
vector<Mat> tvecs;


//prepare camera matrix
Mat intrinsic = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);

//solve calibration
calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, Size(2500,2000), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);


//apply undistortion
string inputName = "../B.jpg";
Mat imgB = imread(imgName);
cvtColor(imgB, imgB, CV_BGR2GRAY)
Mat tempImgC;
undistort(imgB, tempImgC, intrinsic, distCoeffs);


//apply perspective transform
double transData[] = { 0, 0, tvecs[0].at<double>(0), 0, 0,,tvecs[0].at<double>(1), 0, 0,  tvecs[0].at<double>(2) };
Mat translate3x3(3, 3, CV_64F, transData);
Mat rotation3x3;
Rodrigues(rvecs[0], rotation3x3);

Mat transRot3x3(3, 3, CV_64F);
rotation3x3.col(0).copyTo(transRot3x3.col(0));
rotation3x3.col(1).copyTo(transRot3x3.col(1));
translate3x3.col(2).copyTo(transRot3x3.col(2));

Mat imgC;
Mat matPerspective = intrinsic*transRot3x3;
warpPerspective(tempImgC, imgC, matPerspective, Size(2500, 2000));

//write
string outputName = "../C.jpg";
imwrite(outputName, imgC); // A JPG FILE IS BEING SAVED
```

And here is the result image ***C***, which doesn't deal with the perspective transformation at all.
[image]

So could someone teach me how to recover ***A***? Thanks.

Comment: Two remarks 1. calibrateCamera normally needs multiple images to be useful, one is not enough 2. I only had a quick look, but I think you're not using rvec and tvec correctly. They are 3D transforms mapping world coordinates to camera coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Added**

OK, guys, simple mistake. I previously used *warpPerspective* to warp images instead of restoring. Since it works that way, I didn't read [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) thoroughly. It turns out that if it is for restoring, the flag *WARP_INVERSE_MAP* should be set. Change the function call to this, and that's it.

```
warpPerspective(tempImgC, imgC, matPerspective, Size(2500, 2000), WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
```

Here is the **new result image** ***C***:
[image]

The only thing concerns me now is the intermediary *tempImgC*, which is the image after *undistort* and before *warpPerspective*. In some tests with different artificial ***B*** s, This image could turn out to be a scaled-up version of ***B*** with distortion removed. That means a lot of information is lost in the outter area. And there is not much to use for *warpPerspective*. I'm thinking maybe to scale down the image in *undistort* and to scale it up in *warpPerspective*. But I'm not sure yet how to calculate the correct scale to preserve all the information in ***B***.

**Added 2**

The last piece of the puzzle is in place. Call *getOptimalNewCameraMatrix* before *undistort* to generate the new camera matrix that preserves all the info in *B*. And pass this new camera matrix to *undistort* and *warpPerspective.*

```
Mat newIntrinsic=getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(intrinsic, distCoeffs, Size(2500, 2000), 1);
undistort(imgB, tempImgC, intrinsic, distCoeffs, newIntrinsic);
Mat matPerspective = newIntrinsic*transRot3x3;
warpPerspective(tempImgC, imgC, matPerspective, Size(2500, 2000), WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
```

The result image ***C*** is the same in this case. But there is a big difference for other cases. For example, with another distorted image ***B1***.
[image]
The result image ***C1*** without new camera matrix looks like this.
[image]
And the result image ***C1*** with new camera matrix maintains the information in ***B1***
[image]

**Added 3**

I realized that as each frame captured by camera needs processing and efficiency is important, I can't afford to use `undistort` and `warpPerspective` for each frame. It's only reasonable to have one map and use `remap` for each frame.

Actually, there is a straight forward way to that, which is `projectPoints`. Since it generates the map from destination image to source image directly, **no intermediary image is needed** and thus loss of information is avoided.

```
// ....
//solve calibration

//generate a 3-channel mat with each entry containing it's own coordinates
Mat xyz(2000, 2500, CV_32FC3);
float *pxyz = (float*)xyz.data;
for (int y = 0; y < 2000; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 2500; x++)
    {
        *pxyz++ = x;
        *pxyz++ = y;
        *pxyz++ = 0;
    }

// project coordinates of destination image,
// which generates the map from destination image to source image directly
xyz=xyz.reshape(0, 5000000);
Mat mapToSrc(5000000, 1, CV_32FC2);
projectPoints(xyz, rvecs[0], tvecs[0], intrinsic, distCoeffs, mapToSrc);
Mat maps[2];
mapToSrc = mapToSrc.reshape(0, 2000);
split(mapToSrc, maps);

//apply map
remap(imgB, imgC, maps[0], maps[1], INTER_LINEAR);
```